# Can I copy files via scp to specific folder in Windows?

Tags: windows, backup, scp

I know I can copy file in "local" folder through command

```
scp ubnt@192.168.1.20:/tmp/system.cfg /home/hp/backup/192.168.1.20/
```

but I'd like to copy this file to folder e.g.:  C:\backup\192.168.20\ or to NAS.

What command is for this?

I need this for automatic daily/weekly through Windows Task Sheduler and batch file. We're local internet provider using technology by Ubiquiti.

My working script is now looking like that

```
scp ubnt@192.168.1:/tmp/system.cfg /home/hp/backupUBNT/192.168.1/
scp ubnt@192.168.5:/tmp/system.cfg /home/hp/backupUBNT/192.168.5/
scp ubnt@192.168.9:/tmp/system.cfg /home/hp/backupUBNT/192.168.9/
robocopy c:\users\hp\backupUBNT c:\Backup *.* /E
```